# Highlight or change border or background of @Html.DropDownList when it has the focus

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

this works for text input:

```
$('input:text').focus(
    function () {
        $(this).css({ 'border-color': '#66CCFF' });
        $(this).css({ 'box-shadow': '0px 0px 10px #66CCFF'});
    });
```

How can I do this for a pulldown? I have 3 pulldowns along the tab route for choosing but I can't seem to set the border or background. I would be happer with a box-shadow, but if that doesn't work a background would be ok or just a thicker border.  I can't seem to get anything to work.
regular text input on focus/blur works (it's inside a document.ready in the _Layout.cshtml file.)

But a simple alert doesn't even work for a pulldown. Checkbox would be nice too.

```
$('input:select').focus(
    function () {
        alert("inside select");

    });

$('input:checkbox').focus(
    function () {
         alert("inside checkbox");

    });
```

Comment: `$('input:select')` should be just `$('select')`

Answer (score 1):

You can use some css hack - put your selectbox in some div, make selectbox with transparent background and on focusing, add class .focus to parent div.

Something like this

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrap">
  <select>
    <option>test 1</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
select {
   background: transparent;
   border: none;
}
.wrap {float: left;}
.focused {
   background: yellow;
   border: 1px solid #336699;
}
```

**JS**

```
$('select').on('focus', function() {
   $(this).closest('.wrap').addClass('focused');
});
```

**DEMO**  http://jsfiddle.net/R5PXH/477/

Here are some links how to make custom selectboxes with pure css

http://codepen.io/ericrasch/pen/zjDBx

https://coderwall.com/p/w7npmq/fully-custom-select-box-simple-css-only

Let me know, if you still have any questions